# py2exe giving no attribute '__getitem__' but script is fine

Tags: python, py2exe

Here is the trace back while I am converting my python script to exe using py2exe

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scarpV4.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "ntpath.pyc", line 205, in dirname
  File "ntpath.pyc", line 170, in split
  File "ntpath.pyc", line 125, in splitdrive
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

in my scrapV4.py file line 10 is

```
currentPath = os.path.dirname(inspect.getsourcefile( lambda:None ))
```

And here is my comple code http://pastebin.com/RXDCb63r

Please help me figure out this problem.

PS:script itself is working fine

Comment: Why don't you just use `os.getcwd()`?

Comment: @Blender Thanks.Please use your comment as answer.It fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you use *zipfile* option in

```
setup(options = {"py2exe":
                    {"compressed": CompressLevel,
                     "optimize": OptimizeLevel, 
                     "bundle_files": BundleFiles}},
      zipfile = None,
      console = [ProgramName])
```

check value of this option. If you don't want use zipfile option, it's must be **None**, otherwise it's must be name of **library.zip** with dependent libraries which you use in your program.

In my case, the error in this option results in the same errors as you.